# how to mask a image in another image w jimp

Tags: javascript, image, jimp

I want to mask a image in another image like this

[the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gz8p.png)

where this image [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w70ut.png)

is being masked over this [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTzdO.png)

```
const Jimp = require('jimp');
module.exports = async d => {
  const data = d.util.aoiFunc(d);
  const [c = ""] = data.inside.splits;

  

const plate = await Jimp.read('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1082539845609598976/1097835331698565160/Untitled2_20230418163013.png');
const card = await Jimp.read('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1090951194467381301/1090966064206188604/Untitled108_20230330173407.png');


plate.mask(card, 0, 0);
 

await plate.writeAsync(`path/output.png`);
  
  return { code: d.util.setCode(data) };
};
```

I tried this, it does gives me a masked image but the output is in black and white
[the actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABb5j.png)

Comment: Perhaps using:    await plate.composite(card, 0, 0);